# How to set up environment variables on a personal compute instance in Azure Machine Learning Studio using a start up script

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I would like to remove any hard coded keys from my files in Azure Machine Learning Studio and would like to store them as environment variables on my Compute Instance. To do this I attempted to create a start up bash file that exports the relevant environment variables however I am coming across two issues:

- When the script does successfully run, nothing happens i.e. calling printenv <ENV_VAR> does not return anything
- When the start up script fails, I am unable to see the logs from my compute instance and cant seem to understand why given that I am a Contributor on the resource

Used the following bash script as my start up script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u

export VALUE1 = abc
echo $VALUE1
```

Which results in an error as $VALUE1 does not get assigned correctly

I'd really appreciate any help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-customize-compute-instance?view=azureml-api-2#setup-script-logs),  Logs from the setup script execution appear in the logs folder in the compute instance details page.

[image]

As for the bash script, it seems there is a syntax issue.
With below script, I was able to get `echo` result.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e
export VALUE1="abc"
echo "${VALUE1}"
```

For more details and examples, you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-customize-compute-instance?view=azureml-api-2)

Comment: Wow that fixed it, thank you for fixing the code and linking the documentation!